# How to fix AirPods Pro 2 6A301 volume lowering very much for some reason?

Tags: audio, airpods

I use AirPods Pro 2 with Personalised volume and sometimes volume gets lowered very much. I don`t understand what triggers it but want to fix it if possible. I use Spotify, Youtube and Patreon on my phone and sound source.

Do someone else faced such problems?

Are there any known ways to fix this problem besides turning off personalised volume?